# How to acquire Minecraft: Education?

Tags: legal, minecraft-education-edition

I am teaching a young kid programming and he is super into Minecraft world. I found out that **Minecraft: Education** has this thing called an *Agent* that can be controlled via a code-blocks type of commands. Checked more info and videos – looks awesome. The problem is: **How do I get this education version?**

I do not belong to any educational/academic organization, do not have a O365 licence and do not have an e-mail from an `edu` domain (e-mail that is issued/provided by educational/academic organization). What I do is home-schooling (like a private teacher). I am located in Latvia, in case it matters.

The kid already has a Minecraft: Java version, but I see that it does not support this Agent. I tried to connect to the Code Connection app and (as I expected) it did not work.

As I googled this topic, I could not find a way for regular people to get (buy?) Minecraft: Education. Could anyone help in this situation? My goal is to have this Agent or even get an Education version since it has a super-duper huge amount of awesome guides, classes, tutorials and classroom tasks.

Although *Code of Hour* and *Voyage Aquatic* are great projects on their own, that is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Contact Minecraft.... Or perhaps the kid's school can help  with a download...

Answer (score 2):

You can download the installation file for the education edition [here](https://education.minecraft.net/get-started/download/). It will ask you to log in with an e-mail adress when you try to run the game and it looks like you have to be [eligible](https://minecrafteducation.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001427448-Eligibility-for-Minecraft-Education-Edition).

You can find more information about the education edition [here](https://education.minecraft.net/get-started/)

Depending on your circumstances, [this](https://code.org/minecraft) may be a good option, too.

If none of this applies to you, then you can contact the support in the [support center](https://minecrafteducation.zendesk.com/hc/en-us)

Comment: And here lays the problem - I am *not* eligible because I do not work in any education organizations and what I do is home-schooling (like a private teacher). Thank You for the effort, but I already read all this information before and "Code of Hour" and "Voyage Aquatic" is not what I am looking for.

Comment: @KristapsVilerts: Home-schooling is listed on [one of the provided sources](https://minecrafteducation.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001427448-Eligibility-for-Minecraft-Education-Edition).

Comment: Ok, thanks - will look into this!

Comment: Checked that and.. yeah, it basically is the same as in other options. I still need to belong to some kind of organization. Source - https://minecrafteducation.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001432907-Getting-Started-Homeschool-